# Javascript fabric.js function properties of a line

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm a little new to javascript so just trying to learn here, but why does one function return a value, but the other will not?  Let me further explain:

For example:

```
'''
canvas.on({
    'object:moved': updateNewLineCoordinates,
    'selection:created': updateNewLineCoordinates,
    'selection:updated': updateNewLineCoordinates,
    'mouse:dblclick': addingControlPoints
});
'''
```

When I double click the mouse this function executes

```
'''
function addingControlPoints(o) {
    let obj = o.target;  // Object is defined without issue.
    console.log(obj);
}
'''
```

The console outputs the properties the line that I double clicked on.

However, when I select the line, this function executes:

```
'''
function updateNewLineCoordinates(o) {
let obj = o.target;  // Object is Undefined, why?
console.log(obj);
'''
```

The console outputs that the object is undefined.  I cannot understand the "why"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that selection events have a slightly different shape than regular mouse events. When you click a mouse an event is triggered that tells you what it was clicked on. Mouse events are very standard in Javascript, but Fabric gives events a `subTargets` property in case your click touches several targets at once.

Fabric's `selection` events, expect to return a *list* of objects inside the selection. A good way to get a picture of what is going on is by going to the [FabricJS Events demo](http://fabricjs.com/events) and uncheck everything except the `selection` events. You will see that `selection: create` returns an object with a property `e` representing the event and a `selected` array representing everything within the selection.

When you select something in the canvas by clicking, the `target` property of the `mouse:down` event will be the same as the object in the `selected` array of the `selection: created` event, which will also be triggered. By contrast when you do a click-and-drag select, the `selection:created` will potentially contain many more objects than the `mouse:down` that started the selection.

Comment: Ah ok.  I've seen that demo page before but didn't realize how to properly use it.  However, looking at the log for a dblclick versus selection, it all appears to be the same.

I Googled several things, but cannot seem to pass along the properties of a draw line if selected.

For example I tried this:
'''
function updateNewLineCoordinates(e) {
    let activeSelection = e.target;
'''

Comment: I see how to use the canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(0)); but then what if you have multiple lines drawn?  How does it know which one was selected.

Comment: AHA!  I finally figured it out.

function updateNewLineCoordinates(o) {
    
    obj = canvas.getActiveObjects(o);

You got me on the right track anyway. :)